# Custom output directory for stylesheets for Octopress/Jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll, octopress

I am wondering how I can generate stylesheets into a custom directory on an Octopress 3x/Jekyll setup.

I have managed to modify settings in `/config.rb` and `/_includes/head.html` so that production stylesheets get written to `/site/css/` which is where I need them to be.

Problem is, probably due to settings in the `Octopress/Jekyll` gems, `/site/stylesheets/` is still being generated.

Technically not make or break, but needlessly verbose as project is quite large with quite a number of stylesheets.

How can I prevent `/site/stylesheets/`being generated alon gside desired `/site/css/` ?

Am I going to going to have to hack the `Octopress/Jekyll` gems?

Due to upgrades, this latter option is not sustainable and so would like to avoid as much as possible. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Really difficult to spot your problem without seeing your code.

Nevertheless, the problem can be a file with a permalink like `permalink: stylesheets/something.css`, or a `defaults` parameter that is set in your `_config.yml` to point to `stylesheets/something`.

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering how I can generate stylesheets into a custom directory on an Octopress 3x/Jekyll setup.

Since octopress is based upon sass it has the `config.rb` which define the folders and paths for the css/sass files.

The file will probably contains this (might be different in your blog)

```
css_dir = 'assets/stylesheets'
sass_dir = 'assets/sass'

# and some other settings as well
images_dir = 'assets/images'
javascripts_dir = 'assets/javascripts'
line_comments = true
```

> ***`css_dir`***
>     The directory where the css stylesheets are kept.
>   It is relative to the project_path.
>   Defaults to `stylesheets`
>
> ***`sass_dir`***
>   The directory where the sass stylesheets are kept.
>   It is relative to the project_path.
>   Defaults to `sass`.

Full documentation and options can be found here:
http://compass-style.org/help/documentation/configuration-reference/